# NSDateComponents issue when want to get previous month

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I have code:

```
let components = NSDateComponents()
components.month -= 1
let dateInTheMiddleOfPeriod = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: NSDate(), options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))!
```

But the dateInTheMiddleOfPeriod is 2015-**11**-18 06:00:12 +0000 , but I expect 2015-**12**-18 06:00:12 +0000 , because I need the date in the previous month. Why does this happen?

Comment: Each unset component is taken as `NSDateComponentUndefined`, which is a very large number. Substracting one is not what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Calendar component method to get the today's Date year and month components, pass day zero and get the month of the resulting date:

---

```
extension Calendar {
    static let iso8601 = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
}
```

---

```
extension Date {
    var year: Int {
        Calendar.iso8601.component(.year, from: self)
    }
    var month: Int {
        Calendar.iso8601.component(.month, from: self)
    }
    var lastDateOfPreviousMonth: Date? {
        DateComponents(calendar: .iso8601, year: year, month: month, day: 0).date
    }
    var previousMonth: Int {
        lastDateOfPreviousMonth?.month ?? 0
    }
}
```

---

```
Date().lastDateOfPreviousMonth  // "28 Feb 2022 00:00"
Date().previousMonth            // 2
```

Comment: I replaced code with calendarUnitToCalculate = NSCalendarUnit.Month;
            dateInTheMiddleOfPeriod = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(calendarUnitToCalculate, value: -1, toDate: dateNow, options: []) . And now it works, thank you

Answer (score 1):

For getting date for one month before you can follow the steps,

1. Create components of current date,
2. Then decrement one month,
3. Finally convert the component to date again.

Example code :

```
let components = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([.Year, .Month, .Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: NSDate())
components.month -= 1
let dateInTheMiddleOfPeriod = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(components)!
print(dateInTheMiddleOfPeriod)
```

Comment: your solution works, but I like Leo Dabus's solution more. But anyway +1